# Image resize using quill-blot-formatter package restricts the scrolling in the react-quill editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am currently using the React-Quill editor and the functionality for image upload is achieved through the 'formats/image' feature provided by Quill.

Image resize option doesn't included in the react-quill editor by default. Consequently, we have incorporated the `quill-blot-formatter` package and registered it with the Quill modules to enable this feature.

Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);

The image resize feature works fine but it prohibits the scrolling effect of the Quill editor if the mouse focus is inside the resize window

[Image resize prohibits editor scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYfZk.png)

If the mouse pointer is outside of the image resize area, scrolling functions properly. Hence some of the listener from the ql-blot-formatter stopsPropagation of the mouse events to the react-quill(the event is not bubbling up to the ql-editor).

Could someone kindly assist me in resolving this issue.?

Below is the code snippet that I've implemented for the reference.

```
QuillEditor.js

import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

const Quill = ReactQuill.Quill;
const Embed = Quill.import('blots/embed');
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter/dist/BlotFormatter';
import { CustomImage } from './CustomPlugins/CustomImage';

//to register uploaded image as blot
Quill.register(CustomImage, true);
// Register image resize
Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);

<ReactQuill
  ref={editorRef}
  className={`w-full ${height} ${className} `}
  formats={formats}
  id={id}
  modules={modules(toolbarId)}
  theme="snow"
  value={state}
  onChange={handleChange}
      />

function modules(toolbarId) {
     return {
      blotFormatter: {
      specs: [CustomImageSpec], //register the custom spec
      align: {
        icons: alignmentStyles,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

```
CustomImageSpec.js

import DeleteIcon from '../../../assets/DeleteIcon.svg';
import { alignToolBar } from './helper';
import ImageSpec from 'quill-blot-formatter/dist/specs/ImageSpec';

// Custom image spec for blot formatter
// Adding delete icon to the blot toolbar on mount phase
export class CustomImageSpec extends ImageSpec {
  img;
  deleteIcon;

  constructor(formatter) {
    super(formatter);
    this.img = null;
    this.deleteIcon = this.createDeleteIcon();
  }

  createDeleteIcon() {
    const spanElement = document.createElement('span');
    const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.src = DeleteIcon;
    imgElement.alt = 'test image';
    const clsList = ['blot-formatter__toolbar-button', 'blot-delete-icon'];
    spanElement.classList.add(...clsList);
    spanElement.appendChild(imgElement);
    spanElement.style.cssText =
      'display: flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor:pointer; user-select:none; padding: 2px';
    spanElement.addEventListener('click', this.onDeleteIconClick);
    return spanElement;
  }

  init() {
    this.formatter.quill.root.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
    this.formatter.quill.root.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
       this.formatter.repositionOverlay();
    });
  }

  getTargetElement() {
    return this.img;
  }

  onDeleteIconClick = () => {
    // Handle delete icon click
    if (this.img) {
      this.img.remove();
      this.formatter.hide();
    }
  };

  onHide() {
    this.img = null;
  }

  onClick = (event) => {
    const el = event.target;
    if (!el || el.tagName !== 'IMG') {
      return;
    }
    this.img = el;
    this.formatter.show(this);
    alignToolBar(this.formatter);
    this.formatter.overlay
      ?.getElementsByClassName('blot-formatter__toolbar')[0]
      ?.appendChild(this.deleteIcon);
  };
}
```

```
CustomImage.js

import { Quill } from 'react-quill';

// eslint-disable-next-line react-refresh/only-export-components
const BaseImage = Quill.import('formats/image');
// const BaseImage = Quill.import('blots/embed')
// eslint-disable-next-line react-refresh/only-export-components
const ATTRIBUTES = ['alt', 'height', 'width', 'style'];

export class CustomImage extends BaseImage {
  static formats(domNode) {
    return ATTRIBUTES.reduce(function (formats, attribute) {
      if (domNode.hasAttribute(attribute)) {
        formats[attribute] = domNode.getAttribute(attribute);
      }
      return formats;
    }, {});
  }
  format(name, value) {
    if (ATTRIBUTES?.indexOf(name) > -1) {
      if (value) {
        this.domNode.setAttribute(name, value);
      } else {
        this.domNode.removeAttribute(name);
      }
    } else {
      super.format(name, value);
    }
  }
}

//to register uploaded image as blot
Quill.register(CustomImage, true);
```

Comment: Could you make an example with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) or  [playcode.io](https://playcode.io/react)